# Keyboard-shortcut for Firefox print preview?

Tags: firefox, printing, keyboard-shortcuts, preview

For testing the print output during web development, I find myself frequently pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> followed by <kbd>V</kbd>. That is, open "File" menu, then execute "Print preview".

This is cumbersome.

Is there a single keyboard-shortcut for that?

In some browsers, this was possible via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, but nowadays this triggers private browsing instead.

Is there some lesser-known undocumented keyboard-shortcut for that? Or, does provide Firefox any means to configure this shortcut on my own?

Answer (score 2):

I found a slightly shorter sequence: <kbd>F10</kbd> followed by <kbd>V</kbd>. This works because "File" is the first menu.

However, this is still cumbersome and I'd love get to know about a real keyboard-shortcut.

Comment: Menu hotkeys do the job, but note that they're locale-specific. E.g. in Polish you'd need to type **F10**, **G**, or **Alt+P**, then **G**.